# TURN server not reachable?

Tags: amazon-ec2, stun

I'm trying to set up a turnserver on a new Amazone EC2 Linux box by putting my address here: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

I'm really not sure what I'm doing. This is what I see when I run the turnserver command:

```
[potatolabs@ip-172-31-31-86 libevent-2.0.21-stable]$ turnserver -a -o -v -n  --no-dtls --no-tls -u potatolabs:turnserverpw -r "banana" -c /etc/turnserver.conf
0: log file opened: /var/tmp/turn_13785_2017-01-06.log
0:
RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Coturn-4.5.0.3 'dan Eider'
0:
Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 4096
0:
Due to the open files/sockets limitation,
max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 2000 (approximately)
0:

==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: DTLS 1.2 is not supported
0: TURN/STUN ALPN is not supported
0: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
0:
0: SQLite is not supported
0: Redis is not supported
0: PostgreSQL is not supported
0: MySQL supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0:
0: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)

=====================================================

0: Domain name:
0: Default realm: banana
0: NO EXPLICIT LISTENER ADDRESS(ES) ARE CONFIGURED
0: ===========Discovering listener addresses: =========
0: Listener address to use: 127.0.0.1
0: Listener address to use: 172.31.31.86
0: Listener address to use: ::1
0: =====================================================
0: Total: 1 'real' addresses discovered
0: =====================================================
0: NO EXPLICIT RELAY ADDRESS(ES) ARE CONFIGURED
0: ===========Discovering relay addresses: =============
0: Relay address to use: 172.31.31.86
0: Relay address to use: ::1
0: =====================================================
0: Total: 2 relay addresses discovered
0: =====================================================
```

This is my /etc/turnserver.conf file:

```
turn:ec2-35-167-40-172.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
user=potatolabs:turnserverpw

# listen ports
listening-port=2222
listening-ip=127.1.1
```

And this is the info i'm putting in that website:

```
STUN or TURN URI: turn:ec2-35-167-40-172.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:2222
TURN username: potatolabs
TURN password: turnserverpw
```

== UPDATE ==

Here are the security groups. I only have SSH available for `inbound` requests now. Which one should I add?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Security group on your instance? Can the instance reach the Internet? Does it have a public IP in a subnet that has an Internet gateway attached? Or does the private subnet have a NAT instance attached to it?

Comment: There's a `Public IP` that i assumed would just work? I mean i can SSH into it using that IP

Comment: Oooo When I look at the security groups i only see ssh. I'll paste the list that I see. Which one should I choose?

Comment: youll need to add port 2222 so that port is open to anyone to connect too. i would say Custom UDP since the site you linked says "If you test just a single TURN/UDP server, this page even allows you to detect when you are using the wrong credential to authenticated."

Comment: under TCP i assume? or another protocol

Comment: no luck even opening up `All TCP` on all ports...

Comment: when i opened it to `All Traffic` it works!!!

Comment: did you try UDP as well? You can try to use telnet to that port to see if it open.

Comment: Yep UDP did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hello @Edmund glad to see it worked for you. I have been struggling to do this from past 3 days. Could you please post a detailed answer? What comment `turnserver xxxxxxx` did you use to set this up? what are the inbound rules did you use? And finally what URL are you using to do this?

Comment: Hello @strongjz, In my case , it is not working even if i allowed all traffic for IPV4 and IPV6(from anywhere).Can you please post a detailed answer?

Comment: Also @bigpotato,